# Script works in console but not in the original code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`$('#edit-post').modal('hide');` works in console, but doesn't work in the script file. I also don't see the new information unless I refresh the page. Thanks in advance! (Suggested solution in the comment section below.)

The script file:

```
var postId = 0;
var postBodyElement = null;

$('.post').find('.interaction').find('.edit').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    postBodyElement = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1];
    var postBody = postBodyElement.textContent;
    //postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    postId = event.target.dataset.postid;
    $('#post-content').val(postBody);
    $('#edit-post').modal();
});

$('#modal-save').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {body: $('#post-content').val(), postId: postId, _token: token}
    })
        .done(function (msg){
            //console.log(msg['message']);
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
            $(postBodyElement).text(msg['new_content']);
            $('#edit-post').modal('hide');
        })
});
```

The file is loaded in the master html using:

```
...

</head>
<body>
    @include('includes.header')
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src={{ URL::to('src/js/app.js') }}></script>
</body>
</html>
```

After I hit "save" button in the modal it should close automatically and the page should be reflect the new data.

Comment: Does your code reach your `.done` method?

Comment: well does it find the element? Does the done get called? console.log() is your friend.

Comment: The user seems to always have to click the edit button before `postBodyElement` is no longer null. Is this intended? Else there's the issue. Try to code this without using global variables var postID and var postBodyElement to ensure postBodyElement  is no longer null. Or at least throw an error if postBodyElement is still null when you try to turn it into a jquery object with `$(postBodyElement )`. The modal won't hide if the line above threw an uncatched error. Hence it works in the console but not in the code.

Comment: @Radonirina Maminiaina Yes, I can see the new information in the console and after I refresh the page.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, It does find the element and .done() is called.

Comment: @Shilly I need the postId and postBodyElement variable in another file. Hence, the global variables. The variable should capture the unique id of each post and the content after the edit button is clicked.

Comment: You can just reselect the elements.... Using global variables to share data can and will cause bugs when used liberally, so be careful that you don't create too much stress for future you. The id should be an attribute on the post itself so you can just use `event.target.......id`. And postBodyElement is then just querySelector( theID ) . No globals needed.

Comment: Try to place your code inside document ready callback, like that: `$(document).ready(function(){
   //your code here
});`

Comment: @ U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg Thanks! That solved the problem.